# JButton ActionListener is working for some methods but not others

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a button that can read settings from a file, then repaint the GUI with the selected settings so it's easy to review. Additionally, I would like a button to delete a selected file.

I have managed to create a button to save files and one to start the program, but the other two won't work. the only thing that works is `dispose();`.

```
public class NewProfileGui extends JFrame {
    APIContext ctx;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JTextField profileName;
    private JButton saveProfileButton;
    private JComboBox effBox;
    private JCheckBox aBox;
    private JCheckBox sBox;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JComboBox<String> profileBox;
    private JButton loadProfileButton;


    Profile profile;
    File[] files;

    public NewProfileGui(APIContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.profile = new Profile(ctx);

        files = profile.getProfiles();

        for (File i: files) {
            profileBox.addItem(i.getName());
        }

        saveProfileButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            boolean sBox = sBox.isSelected();
            boolean aBox = aBox.isSelected();
            int efficiency = effBox.getSelectedIndex();
            String name = profileName.getText();

            profile.saveProfile(name,
                    sBox ,
                    aBox ,
                    efficiency
        });

        loadProfileButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            File f = (File) profileBox.getSelectedItem();
            profile.loadProfile(f);
            effBox.setSelectedItem(ProfileData.eff);
            aBox.setSelected(ProfileData.antiBan);
            sBox.setSelected(ProfileData.sellFish);
            this.repaint();
        });

        deleteProfileButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            File f = (File) profileBox.getSelectedItem();
            profile.deleteProfile(f);
            });

        startButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (start()) {
                dispose();
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
}

private boolean start() {
        ProfileData.sBox = sBox.isSelected();
        ProfileData.aBox = aBox.isSelected();
        ProfileData.eff = effBox.getSelectedIndex();
        ProfileData.start = true;
        return true;
    }
}

public class Profile {
    APIContext ctx;
    GsonBuilder builder;
    Gson gson;

    public Profile(APIContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.setPrettyPrinting();
        gson = builder.create();
    }
    public void saveProfile(
            String fileName,
            boolean sBox,
            boolean aBox ,
            int eff) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Settings settings = createSettingsObject(
                sBox ,
                aBox ,
                eff);

        // Java objects to String
        // String json = gson.toJson(staff);

        File directory = ctx.script().getSettingsDirectory();
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        // Java objects to File
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(directory + "\\" + fileName + ".json")) {
            gson.toJson(settings, writer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public File[] getProfiles() {
        return ctx.script().getSettingsDirectory().listFiles();
    }

    public void loadProfile(File file) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (file == null) {
            try (Reader reader = new FileReader(ctx.script().getScriptProfile().get().getAbsolutePath())) {

                // Convert JSON File to Java Object
                Settings settings = gson.fromJson(reader, Settings.class);

                // print settings object
                System.out.println(settings);

                settings.applySettings(true);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try (Reader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
                // Convert JSON File to Java Object
                Settings settings = gson.fromJson(reader, Settings.class);

                // print settings object
                System.out.println(settings);

                settings.applySettings(false);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    //Delete selected profile
    public void deleteProfile(File file){
        if (file != null) {
            file.deleteOnExit();
        }
    }

   private static Settings createSettingsObject(
            boolean sBox ,
            boolean aBox ,
            int eff) {
        Settings settings = new Settings();

        settings.setSBox(sBox);
        settings.setABox(aBox);
        settings.setEff(eff);

        return settings;

    }
}

class Settings {
    private boolean sBox;
    private boolean aBox;
    private int eff;

    public void applySettings(boolean start) {
        ProfileData.sBox = sBox;
        ProfileData.aBox = aBox;
        ProfileData.eff = eff;
        ProfileData.start = start;
    }

    /***SET METHODS***/
    public void setSellFish(boolean sBox) {
        this.sBox = sBox;
    }

    public void setAntiBan(boolean aBox) {
        this.aBox = aBox;
    }

    public void setEff(int eff) {
        this.eff = eff;
    }
```

Comment: Also consider `java.util.prefs.Preferences`.

Comment: *but the other two wont work.* - define won't work? Did you add debug code to the ActionListener to see if the code is invoked? If the ActionListener is invoked did you step through the logic to see what is happening?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre] that will compile for others.